# How to define a custom widget using both XML and java code

Tags: android, custom-controls

I want to define a custom widget, which contains some other controls and has own logic. I want to use XML file to define the UI, and the java code to define the logic. But I don't know how to do it.

I followed this article [Building mix-up custom Android component/widget using Java class and XML layout](http://maohao.wordpress.com/2009/08/27/building-mix-up-custom-component-android/), but don't a working one. Following is my code.

XML:

```
<com.example.MyView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="custom button 1"/>

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="custom button 2"/>

</com.example.MyView>
```

Java code:

```
public class MyView extends LinearLayout {

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.test_view, this);  // **line 32**
    }
}
```

And in the main layout, I invoke it like this:

```
<com.example.MyView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</com.example.MyView>
```

Unfortunately, it throws an exception when running:

```
05-26 14:11:25.199: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15799): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.MyActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
    at com.example.MyView.onFinishInflate(MyView.java:32)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:631)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
    at com.example.MyView.onFinishInflate(MyView.java:32)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:631)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
    at com.example.MyView.onFinishInflate(MyView.java:32)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:631)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
    at com.example.MyView.onFinishInflate(MyView.java:32)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:631)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
    ....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't declare the custom view like you did. If you use your custom view in the main layout the `onFinishInflate` method will be called to construct the custom view and in that method the layout above will be called. The problem is that you already have a custom view reference in that layout(which will be inflated again when the `LayoutInflater` encounters the custom view tag) so you'll get in a circular inflating situation.

You probably want something like this:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android>

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="custom button 1"/>

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="custom button 2"/>

</merge>
```

so when your custom view will be inflated from a layout file it will append the content of the xml layout above. The `onFinishInflate` method will remain the same:

```
@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();
    LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.test_view, this);  // **line 32**
}
```

**Edit**: It appears that inflating a content layout in the `onFinishInflate` method triggers the method again(at least on older versions). You could either modify the layout to use a `LinearLayout` like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="custom button 1"/>

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="custom button 2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and then in the `onFinishInflate` method:

```
@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.aaaaaaaaaaa, this, false); 
    addView(v);
}
```

This will introduce another useless element in the layout hierarchy so you might simply inflate the layout with `merge` tag in the constructors of the custom view:

```
public MyView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.test_view, this);
}

public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.test_view, this);
}

public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.test_view, this);
}
```

Comment: `merge` doesn't work neither. The error message is `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class <unknown>`

Comment: It's working on my android 4.1 pad, but not my android 2.3 mobile. How to make it working on android 2.3(even 2.2)?

Comment: @Freewind Did you add the android namespace to the `merge` tag? `<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >...`

Comment: I did, exactly the same as yours.